# Find all complex numbers $z_{1},z_{2},..,z_{n}$ knowing that $z_{i}=(1-b)a+bz_{\sigma(i)}$

Tags: complex-numbers, permutations

We have $a,b$ complex numbers and $b^{m}\neq1$ for every $m$ natural number. Find all complex numbers $z_{1},z_{2},..,z_{n}$ knowing that $z_{i}=(1-b)a+bz_{\sigma(i)}$, for every $i\in\left\{1,2,..,n\right\}$, where $\sigma$ is a fixed permutation from $S_{n}$.

Comment: IMHO : a somewhat twisted question... A hint for starting : consider the similitude (rotation combined with homothety) defined by $s(z)=Az+B$ where $A=b$ and $B=(1-b)a$

Comment: @Bongo You are right ! I erase it !

Answer (score 2):

let's sum all equations: $$\sum z_i=n(1-b)a+b\sum z_i\implies a=\frac{1}{n}. $$
now decompose permutation $\sigma$ in his cycle (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Cycle_notation)
unless you rename the $z_i$'s, you can assume that  $\sigma=(1,2,\ldots,n_1)(n_1+1,\ldots,n_2)\ldots(n_{k-1},\ldots,n_k)$, with $n_k=n$. Now $z_i$ and $z_j$ have no relation between them for $i\le n_1, j>n_1$, so i can assume that
$\sigma=(1,\ldots,n)$ ($\sigma$ actually must be done just like this, if not, redoing the initial reasoning I would find that $a=\frac{1}{n}=\frac{1}{n_1}$).
Now we get: $$z_1=\frac{1-b}{n}+bz_{\sigma(1)}=\frac{1-b}{n}+bz_2 =\frac{1-b}{n}+b(\frac{1-b}{n}+bz_{3})=\ldots $$
$$=\frac{1-b}{n}(1+b+\ldots+b^{n-1})+b^{n}z_{n+1}=  \frac{1-b}{n}(1+b+\ldots+b^{n-1})+b^{n}z_1$$ $$\implies z_1=\frac{1}{n}\implies \frac{1}{n}=\frac{1-b}{n}+bz_2\implies z_2=\frac{1}{n}\ldots\implies z_i=\frac{1}{n}\text{ for } i=1,\ldots,n .$$